# How to properly include mdi into Angular2 webpack

Tags: include, angular, webpack, mdi

Could you please help me with step by step guide (or link if you know of some) on how to include material design icons into angular2 webpack?

I did install it through both npm install mdi (one resource I've found was mentioning it like this) and npm install material-design-icons (from https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons). I also tried it through dependencies.

But that's not enough. As I understand it I have to also say to webpack that he should use it. But I don't know how and I cant find anything about it.

So right now I'm using it like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.3/angular-material.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/1.4.57/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
```

But that's not how I want to do it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I hope you'd have found the answer now, but if not follow these instruction

1. Install material design icon via npm: `npm install mdi --save`
2. I hope you might be using `angular-cli`. If so open `angular-cli.json` and in the "styles" array add

   ```
   "styles": [
           "../node_modules/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
         ]
   ```
3. Next in the `addons` add the fonts as follows

> ```
> "addons": [
>          "../node_modules/mdi/fonts/*.+(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)"
>       ],
> ```

4. Stop the console and `ng server`. To test this works, add this to a component and check. `<i class="mdi mdi-sitemap mdi-24px">`
5. If it works, then you've successfully added mdi icons to angular 2 project

Comment: In my case it worked without step 3, is it really needed? EDIT: Maybe because I'm using the SASS version instead of the CSS one.